# How to get rows between 20.00 and 8.00 in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get dates between 2 times like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `test` 
WHERE hour(tm) BETWEEN 20 and 8;
```

columne `tm` is Time type.
In my Test table i have next valuse in `tm` columne:

```
10:00:00
08:00:00
15:00:00
20:00:00
21:00:00
```

Code does not work.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Add quotes,  `BETWEEN '08' and '20';`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a direct comparison with time literals:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE tm < '08:00:00' OR tm >= '20:00:00';
```

Comment: Yes, but i need tm > 20 and tm < 8. So time at the night

Comment: That totally changes the logic but in any case I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `test` 
WHERE hour(tm) >= '20' or  hour(tm) <=  '08';
```

> Result:
>
> ```
>  08:00:00
>  20:00:00
>  21:00:00
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d00bb75daacc4e7de9ad0d45ed805776)

Comment: That probably won't use the index if there is one on the tm column.

Comment: Yes, but i need tm > 20 and tm < 8. So time at the night